# My hover effect shows grey area before image load in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, dom-events

I am a web-developer and soon launched a website, the thing is, that I've made a hover effect on the images thumbs that first shows an enlarged small thumb and immediately afterwards shows the big thumb, both the same size, so the effect is that first you see a blury image and then the full image.
It works good in IE, Opera and Firefox but on Google Chrome, instead of the small thumb enlarged, it shows a grey screen and it drives me crazy. 
I've searched everywhere, but to no avail.

Here's my Javascript function that I use:

```
function trailOn2(thumbimg,imgtitle,username,imgid,imgsize,credit,level,thw,thh,smallmedium,smallThumbPath){
var smallmedium = (smallmedium == null) ? 0 : smallmedium;
var isinstore = 0;
if (thumbimg.indexOf("storeimages/item") >= 0) {
    isinstore = 1;
}
switch(smallmedium)
{
    case 1:
        var thumbimgprev = thumbimg.replace('/thumbs/400x149', '/thumbs/142x52');
        break;
    case 0:
        var thumbimgprev = thumbimg.replace('/thumbs/400x149', '/thumbs/142x52');
        break;
    case 2:
        var thumbimgprev = thumbimg.replace(/thumbs/, "small");
        break;
}
thumbimgprev=smallThumbPath;
gettrailobj().left="-500px";
divthw = parseInt(thw) + 2;
smthw = parseInt(thw) + 2;
halfthh = 50;
halfthh = Math.ceil(parseInt(thh)/2);
topx = halfthh - 9;
smthh = parseInt(thh) + 2;
var static_adr = 'http://www.timelineimages.com/'

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")!=-1)
    htm2 = 'border-width:0px;margin:0px;z-index:53;layer-background-color: #F0F3F6;background-color:#F0F3F6;padding:3px;';
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari")!=-1)
    htm2 = 'border-width:0px;margin:0px;z-index:53;layer-background-color: #F0F3F6;background-color:#F0F3F6;padding:3px;';      
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){
    htm2='border-width:0px;margin:0px;z-index:53;layer-background-color: #F0F3F6;background-color:#F0F3F6;padding:3px;';
}else{
    htm2='border-width:0px;margin:0px;z-index:53;layer-background-color: #F0F3F6;background-color:#F0F3F6;padding:3px;';
}

html = '<div id="div_2" style="'+htm2+'">'+imgtitle+'<br>'+'</div></div><div style="visibility:hidden"><div style="height:'+thh+'px">&nbsp;</div>';

htm ='';
htm+='<div style="width:'+divthw+'px;height:100%;border: 1px none #ffffff; padding:10px;z-index:51 ">';
    htm+='<div style="width:'+thw+'px;background-color: #FFFFFF; layer-background-color: #FFFFFF;z-index:51">';
        htm+='<div style="border-width:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;background-color: #ffffff; layer-background-color: #ffffff;z-index:51;position:absolute;width:'+thw+'px;height:'+smthh+'px">';

            htm+='<img  src="'+thumbimgprev+'" width="'+smthw+'" height="'+smthh+'" border="0">';
        htm+='</div>';
        htm+='<div style="border-width:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;z-index:52;position:absolute;text-align: center;width:'+thw+'px;top:'+topx+'px;">';
        htm+='</div>';
        htm+='<div style="border-width:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;z-index:51;position:absolute;width:'+thw+'px;">';
            htm+='<div style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;width:'+thw+'px;">';
                htm+='<img name="btcontainer" id="btcontainer" src="'+static_adr+'images/separator.gif" border="0" width="'+thw+'" height="'+thh+'" >';
        ///////////////////////
        htme='</div>';
    htme+='</div>';
htme+='</div>';
gettrailobject().innerHTML = htm+html+htme;
gettrailobject().style.zIndex=100;

if (document.getElementById)
    document.getElementById('btcontainer').src = thumbimg;
else if (document.all)
    document.all.btcontainer.src = thumbimg;
gettrailobj().visibility="visible";
divw = parseInt(thw)+25;
divh = parseInt(thh)+130;
mm_hoverThumb=1;
document.onmousemove=followmouse;
 }

function truebody()
 {

if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') > -1)
{
    return document.body;
}

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('opera') > -1 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1  || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1 )
{
    return document.documentElement;
}

 }
function followmouse(e)
{
    var docwidth=document.all? truebody().scrollLeft+truebody().clientWidth : pageXOffset+window.innerWidth-15
    var docheight=document.all? Math.min(truebody().scrollHeight, truebody().clientHeight) : Math.min(document.body.offsetHeight, window.innerHeight)
    if(typeof e != "undefined")
    {
    if(docwidth < 15+e.pageX+divw)
        xcoord = e.pageX-divw-5;
    else
        xcoord = 15+e.pageX;
    if(docheight < 15+e.pageY+divh)
        ycoord = 15+e.pageY-Math.max(0,(divh + e.pageY - docheight - truebody().scrollTop - 30));
    else
        ycoord = 15+e.pageY;
    }
    else if (typeof window.event != "undefined")
    {
    if(docwidth < 15+truebody().scrollLeft+event.clientX+divw)
        xcoord = truebody().scrollLeft-5+event.clientX-divw;
    else
        xcoord = truebody().scrollLeft+15+event.clientX;

    if(docheight < 15+truebody().scrollTop+event.clientY+divh)
        ycoord = 15+truebody().scrollTop+event.clientY-Math.max(0,(divh + event.clientY - docheight - 30));
    else
        ycoord = truebody().scrollTop+15+event.clientY;
    }
    gettrailobj().left=xcoord+"px"
    gettrailobj().top=ycoord+"px"
    }

    Array.prototype.in_array = function ( obj ) {
    var len = this.length;
    for ( var x = 0 ; x <= len ; x++ ) {
        if ( this[x] == obj ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You need all this code for that little effect that you described?

Comment: @Amberlamps It`s not my code, I`m just trying to fix it.

Comment: any errors in dev tools?

Comment: you might be better of re-writing it. looks pretty bloated for a simple task

Comment: If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, this effect can be done pretty fast, pretty easy and cross-browser, without that whole bunch of code. But anyway, can you provide a link to a sample to see what is going on?

Comment: @Angel: Please load http://www.timelineimages.com/search-cover-photos/women in Google Chrome and scroll over a picture, then scroll over a picture in other browsers. You will notice the grey area first loads up in GC and in FF for example it`s the picture, without no errors in the console.

Comment: @Gabriel: I really can't make out the tails and heads in your code, but I suspect you want to wait for image to be loaded before showing the floating box.

Comment: @bvukelic: No. The floating box is showed first with the thumb being stretched to the size of the larger thumb and then immediately afterwards is shown the larger thumb. This effect is managed by handling onmouseover combined with visibility and z-index. Check out the link I gave Angel, just 2 comments up. Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel: In my opinion your question is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you want people to check your code!

Comment: @Amberlamps: I don`t want people to check my code, it's just there for reference. The question is actually about cross-browser interoperability. Read again my question.

Comment: @Gabriel: What I mean is, the grey area appears because the image is not yet loaded. So you want to hide the floating box until you are sure that image is loaded and THEN show the floating box. In jQuery, you can use the .load() handler. I don't know how you'd do that in pure JS, but you can probably find that out on your own.

Comment: @bvukelic: If what you say it`s true, why the difference between browsers? Why does FF loads it and GC shows a grey area? Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: @Gabriel: In FF, I see a broken image icon that appears right before image is loaded. Different browser show 'empty' images differently, and we have to live with it.

Comment: Here's one solution: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317

Comment: That is not because of your js code, but it is the way browsers handle image download. And, by the way, in FF happens the same thing from time to time, it depends on the time needed to download the image. One fix would be to show a white background instead of that grey, and put inside it a loading gif... until it is loaded. That I think would be more user-friendly.

Comment: You can do that easily, by having a div inside that container, that contains the loading gif, and has z-index lower than the z-index of the div that will load the image. And when the image will be available for display, it will overlap the loading gif. Loading gif will still be there, but it will not be visible. That's easy to do.

Comment: I think a better way to do it is create a IMG node that is detached from the DOM, and when image is loaded, replace the loading gif with the IMG node. The reason I think it's better is it doesn't increase the DOM complexity (which makes the page slow a bit), and you don't have to mess with styling the image container so that it doesn't conflict with loading gif container, etc. (See my answer below about using Image() constructor to preload images.)

Comment: I just got an idea from checking out iStock. Instead of using the loading GIF, you can use the small thumbnail as a proxy until the large one loads.

Comment: @bvukelic: That`s exactly what it should suppose to do, but instead of the small thumb as proxy it shows a grey screen in Chrome. But I`m seconds away from finding the bug, I`ll let you know what it was once I`m sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the whole source code function:

```
function trailOn2(thumbimg,imgtitle,username,imgid,imgsize,credit,level,thw,thh,smallmedium,smallThumbPath){
var smallmedium = (smallmedium == null) ? 0 : smallmedium;
var isinstore = 0;
if (thumbimg.indexOf("storeimages/item") >= 0) {
    isinstore = 1;
}
switch(smallmedium)
{
    case 1:
        var thumbimgprev = thumbimg.replace('/thumbs/400x149', '/thumbs/142x52');
        break;
    case 0:
        var thumbimgprev = thumbimg.replace('/thumbs/400x149', '/thumbs/142x52');
        break;
    case 2:
        var thumbimgprev = thumbimg.replace(/thumbs/, "small");
        break;
}
thumbimgprev=smallThumbPath;
gettrailobj().left="-500px";
divthw = parseInt(thw) + 2;
smthw = parseInt(thw) + 2;
halfthh = 50;
halfthh = Math.ceil(parseInt(thh)/2);
topx = halfthh - 9;
smthh = parseInt(thh) + 2;
var static_adr = 'http://www.timelineimages.com/'

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")!=-1)
    htm2 = 'border-width:0px;margin:0px;z-index:53;layer-background-color: #F0F3F6;background-color:#F0F3F6;padding:3px;';
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari")!=-1)
    htm2 = 'border-width:0px;margin:0px;z-index:53;layer-background-color: #F0F3F6;background-color:#F0F3F6;padding:3px;';      
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){
    htm2='border-width:0px;margin:0px;z-index:53;layer-background-color: #F0F3F6;background-color:#F0F3F6;padding:3px;';
}else{
    htm2='border-width:0px;margin:0px;z-index:53;layer-background-color: #F0F3F6;background-color:#F0F3F6;padding:3px;';
}

html = '<div id="div_2" style="'+htm2+'">'+imgtitle+'<br>'+'</div></div><div style="visibility:hidden"><div style="height:'+thh+'px">&nbsp;</div>';

htm ='';
htm+='<div style="width:'+divthw+'px;height:100%;border: 1px none #ffffff; padding:10px;z-index:51 ">';
    htm+='<div style="width:'+thw+'px;background-color: #FFFFFF; layer-background-color: #FFFFFF;z-index:51">';
        //here htm+='<div style="border-width:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;background-color: #ffffff; layer-background-color: #ffffff;z-index:51;position:absolute;width:'+thw+'px;height:'+smthh+'px">';

         //and here    htm+='<img  src="'+thumbimgprev+'" width="'+smthw+'" height="'+smthh+'" border="0">';
    //and this one here     htm+='</div>';
        htm+='<div style="border-width:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;z-index:52;position:absolute;text-align: center;width:'+thw+'px;top:'+topx+'px;">';
        htm+='</div>';
        htm+='<div style="border-width:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;z-index:51;position:absolute;width:'+thw+'px;">';


            htm+='<div style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;width:'+thw+'px;">';
   /*and here changed the src with the small thumb*/              htm+='<img name="btcontainer" id="btcontainer" src="'+thumbimgprev+'" border="0" width="'+thw+'" height="'+thh+'" >';
            ///////////////////////
           htme='</div>';
    htme+='</div>';
htme+='</div>';
gettrailobject().innerHTML = htm+html+htme;
gettrailobject().style.zIndex=100;

if (document.getElementById)
    document.getElementById('btcontainer').src = thumbimg;
else if (document.all)
    document.all.btcontainer.src = thumbimg;
gettrailobj().visibility="visible";
divw = parseInt(thw)+25;
divh = parseInt(thh)+130;
mm_hoverThumb=1;
document.onmousemove=followmouse;
 }
```

I've deleted a whole div that was useless and changed the last image src, look for comment, with the small thumb that needed loading.

```
  //here htm+='<div style="border-width:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;background-color: #ffffff; layer-background-color: #ffffff;z-index:51;position:absolute;width:'+thw+'px;height:'+smthh+'px">';

     //and here    htm+='<img  src="'+thumbimgprev+'" width="'+smthw+'" height="'+smthh+'" border="0">';
//and this one here     htm+='</div>';
```

If the element was loaded, my function replaced it's src with the big one.

```
 htm+='<img name="btcontainer" id="btcontainer" src="'+thumbimgprev+'" border="0" width="'+thw+'" height="'+thh+'" >';
```

Thanks for your answers, I've managed to finish a big chunk of code with your help.
As a side note here though, I would've done it using jquery, but this is what the company offered me to do, this is what I've done.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I didn't had the willpower to look through your code. So, here is an alternative that works in modern browsers. Like Chrome, you might want to use your code as fallback if an approach like the one below isn't supported (like for Internet Explorer).

**demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/LpVqD/

**html sample**

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1" data-large="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2" data-large="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/2" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3" data-large="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/3" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/4" data-large="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/4" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/5" data-large="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/5" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/6" data-large="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/6" /></li>
</ul>​
```

**css sample**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
li img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover img {
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
​
```

**javascript**

```
$('img').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('large'));
});
​
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the image-not-loaded-yet problem.

Comment: yes it does. Try it in chrome.

Comment: No it doesn't. Check with a large image that takes a while to load. Also, there's another problem. Once it shows the large version, it also replaces the small thumbnail with the large image, which is probably not desirable here.

Comment: @bvukelic - http://jsfiddle.net/LpVqD/2/ - larger images, works flawlessly. You see blurry images until the large version is loaded. I don't deliver a ready-to-use code, since I'm doing this for free. Adding a "return to small image feature" really isn't a problem. (I added it to the update).

Comment: That only works with progressive compression, which is not always the case. Progressive starts loading with a lower-resolution proxy, and then 'progressively' loads up to full resolution. While that does make it a slightly better solution than the original, it's by no means a complete solution. Especially with slow servers.

Comment: Another point here is that the container for the larger thumbnail might contain information other than just the large thumbnail at some point in future. It may not be the case now, but I'm sure it will become a requirement at some point in future. For example: http://www.istockphoto.com/search/lightbox/10333616?isource=EN_PHOTOS1#25742ff If that becomes a requirement, your solution would become invalid. So sticking to a proper floating container would be best even at this stage.

Comment: @bvukelic - oh boy... I added another update to prove that the blurry image **is** the enlarged small one and not the progressive load of the large one. http://jsfiddle.net/LpVqD/3/ loads a different image for the larger version.

The question doesn't talk about a floating container, it says `a hover effect on the images thumbs that first shows an enlarged small thumb and immediately afterwards shows the big thumb`. I don't know for what it will be used.

Comment: @bvukelic anyway, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Yes, now I see what is going on. I cannot retract the downvote since you haven't edited the answer meanwhile, but FTR, I would retract it now if I could. However, that doesn't say I agree with the answer. Your solution only works because you are replacing the SRC attribute in the IMG element itself. As the OP says, he needs the gray box gone, and your solution is still not adequate.

Comment: Your solution would work though, if you copied the small thumbnail's IMG node into the floating box, and then did what you did in your example without the CSS scaling, etc.

Comment: @bvukelic. Indeed, the gray box is gone because there is no box that could be gray. Of course, if the OP wants a floating box (which he never asked for), my answer would be incomplete. If he wants to show more infos, he would have to insert that info inside each `<li>`, showing it on hover (where, oh surprise, it would be most semantically correct).

Comment: You have to understand that OP is dealing with legacy code, and you don't really have room for finesse in some cases. :)

Comment: @bvukelic. Ok, it was the part about `soon [have to] launch a website` that incorrectly made me think the code for the website is new. My mistake, I'm sorry.